# Input attribuite on the action element equivalent in struts2

Tags: struts2, migration, struts1

What is the equivalent in Struts2 for input attribute on the action element?

```
<action
     path="/testAction"
     type="com.test.TestAction"
     name="test"
     scope="request"
     input="/pages/test.jsp">
     <forward name="success" path="/test.do"/>
     <forward name="error" path="/pages/welcome.jsp"/>
  </action>
```

Comment: I found the answare: <result name="input">path </result>